# Change the property of a rectangle by using another class JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a project and I want a rectangle to appear when I press a button. However, I want to do this by directing the button click to a different class. Here is what I've tried:

Here is my first class, "Main"

```
static boolean btnClicked = false;
    @Override       
    
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    
    Button btn = new Button("Make Popup Visible");
    
    Rectangle menu = new Rectangle(40,40,200,200);
    menu.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    menu.setOpacity(0);
    
    btn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,(MouseEvent e) ->{
        AddRect.showMenu();
    });
    
    if(btnClicked == true) {
        menu.setOpacity(1);
    }
    
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, menu);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

And my second class, "AddRect"

```
public class AddRect {
    static void showMenu() {
        Main.btnClicked = true;
    }
}
```

However, this isn't working, and I don't know why. Can somebody help me? I don't even know if this is the best way to do it (Using two classes), but if there is a better way please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There’s a lot wrong with this code and it’s hard to know where to start. But the bottom line is that the `if (btnClicked == true) { ... }` (why not just `if (btnClicked) {...}`, btw?) is executed before you even display the button, never mind after the user has pressed it. So `btnClicked` will be `false` when that code is executed.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, I think it clicked when you pointed out the fact that I put the conditional before the display, thanks! Also, I put `(btnClicked == true)` instead of `(btnClicked)` because I wanted to make sure that the computer knew I wanted to run it when the boolean was true. I know it doesn't make a difference, but it's just a little thing I do :)

Comment: Just to be clear, it’s not enough just to execute that after the button is displayed, you have to execute it *when the button is pressed*. (At which point the `btnClicked` variable becomes redundant, as you can just change the opacity of the rectangle.)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I was hoping to add more code to the second class later to make the Main class less cluttered, but I'm not sure if it's going to work now.

Comment: Read up on MVC architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I just had to move the conditional inside the EventHandler

```
    btn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,(MouseEvent e) ->{
        AddRect.showMenu();
        if(btnClicked == true) {
            menu.setOpacity(1);
        }
    });
```